# php-mysql query ouptut inside html drop-down menu

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables in database named groups(*groupID, groupName*) and userBelongToGroups(*userID, groupID*).

```
groups                      userBelongToGroups
===================       =====================   
groupID | groupName        userID | groupID
-------------------       ---------------------
   1    | A                   1   |   1
   2    | B                   1   |   2
   3    | C                   2   |   2
   4    | D                   3   |   1
                              3   |   3
                              4   |   4
```

I want to display all values of column *groupName* for the current User inside a drop-down menu.

```
<select class="form-control" id="system_tags" name="system_tags">
     <?php
        $userID = $_SESSION['userID'];

        // select the values from 'groupName' column
        $sql = "SELECT groupName FROM groups, userBelongToGroups WHERE userID = '$userID' and `groups.groupID = userBelongToGroups.groupID`";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        // display the values from 'groupName' table column
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
         echo "<option value='".$row['groupName']."'>".$row['groupName']."</option>";
        } ?>
</select>
```

So when '$userID' = 1, it should display two options A and B inside the drop-down menu.

Note: the SQL query runs perfectly in MySQL.

```
SELECT groupName FROM groups, userBelongToGroups WHERE userID = '1' and groups.groupID = userBelongToGroups.groupID
```

Comment: Try to remove ` around
groups.groupID = userBelongToGroups.groupID

Comment: So... what does it do?  What is the problem?  You see only one, none at all, you have errors in your logs? ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some typographical errors in this part of your query:
[image]

It should read 

`WHERE userID = '$userID' and groups.groupID = userBelongToGroups.groupID";`

Also trying to set the $userID from the session can result from errors if no default value is set. So instead of `$userID = $_SESSION['userID']` you should have something like:

```
$userID = 0; 
if(isset($_SESSION['userID'])){$userID = $_SESSION['userID'];}
```

Finally, you could consider using `JOIN` in such queries, like:

```
SELECT a.groupName FROM groups a JOIN userBelongToGroups b ON a.groupID = b.groupID AND b.userID = '$userID';
```